# Tensorflow: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'eval'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

```
state = cell.zero_state(batchsize, tf.float32).eval()
```

I am trying to follow this https://github.com/kvfrans/twitch/blob/master/sample.py#L45 example to decode and run a trained tensorflow model, but it seems like the tensorflow code used was an older version. I have managed to fix most calls to v 1.0.0, but I am stuck where the code line above gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sample import *
  File "/home/user/twitch/sample.py", line 75, in <module>
    print predict("this game is")
  File "/home/user/twitch/sample.py", line 46, in predict
    state = initialstate.eval()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

Any ideas on how I should fix the `.eval()` and `state`? It is used later in:

```
guessed_logits, state = sess.run([logits, final_state], feed_dict={input_data: primer, initialstate: state})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.eval()` method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#eval) is only implemented on [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor), but as others have observed, the [`cell.zero_state()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/rnn_cell/base_interface_for_all_rnn_cells#RNNCell.zero_state) method returns a `tuple` object.

The [`tf.Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) method understands how to unpack tuples, and `tf.Tensor.eval()` is just a convenient wrapper for calling `tf.Session.run()` on a single tensor in the ["default" session](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_default_session). Using this observation, you can switch this line:

```
state = cell.zero_state(batchsize, tf.float32).eval()
```

...with the following:

```
state = tf.get_default_session().run(cell.zero_state(batchsize, tf.float32))
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run eval on Python objects - tuple in this case.

One option could be to convert the Python Object to tensor first:

```
state = cell.zero_state(batchsize, tf.float32).eval()
```

to:

```
state = tf.convert_to_tensor(cell.zero_state(batchsize, tf.float32))
```

Once it is a tensor, you `eval` it with:

```
state.eval()
```

Comment: It returns with this: `ValueError: Could not flatten dictionary. Key had 4 elements, but value had 1 elements. Key: [<tf.Tensor 'zeros:0' shape=(1, 200) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'zeros_1:0' shape=(1, 200) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'zeros_2:0' shape=(1, 200) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'zeros_3:0' shape=(1, 200) dtype=float32>], value: [<tf.Tensor 'packed:0' shape=(2, 2, 1, 200) dtype=float32>].`

Answer (score 1):

From [TensorFlow Release 1.0.0 notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20170308180003/https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md):

> `LSTMCell`, `BasicLSTMCell`, and `MultiRNNCell` constructors now default to state_is_tuple=True. For a quick fix while transitioning to the new default, simply pass the argument `state_is_tuple=False`.

Which explains the error message you get (you cannot call `.eval()` on a `tuple`).

Comment: I can't turn the `state_is_tuple=False`, how would you recommend fixing it?

Comment: @Blizzard choose the element of the tuple that interests to you and run eval on it.